# Executing shell script FILE with NSTask - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, bash, shell, nstask

i've got a file "Script.sh", which includes different shell commands, like some defaults write or creating folders, moving files etc. For Example:

```
#!/bin/sh
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool TRUE
killall Finder
```

However, im pretty new to Objective C and didnt find any solution to run the whole file with NSTask. I only found some solutions with directly coding it into Objective C.

Is it even possible?

Comment: The correct use is described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183664/using-nstask-to-launch-shell-script-that-launches-node-js

Answer (score -1):

Got it working.
Just set the path of a Shell script as the argument of NSTask and launch it.

```
NSURL *myscript =[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"script" withExtension:@"sh"]; 


NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
task.launchPath = @"/bin/sh";

task.arguments =@[myscript.path];
[task launch];
[task waitUntilExit];
```